# Three.js FBX Load Background Transparency Not Working

Tags: javascript, three.js

I dipping my toes into three.js and have hit a problem with the transparency not working. I'm using a recent build of three js, the fbx file loads and renders fine but no matter what settings I have tweaked I cannot get the background as transparent - it either always defaults to black or tries to read the values as an rgb value. I have tried these settings as suggested by other users:

```
scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0x000000,0 ); (This line appears to be read as rgb?)
scene.background = null;

renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ alpha: true, antialias: true });
renderer.setClearColor( 0x000000, 0 );
```

The fbx load is done inside an iframe and I have double checked the transparency settings on the iframe. Can anybody shed some light on this for me.

Here are the first few lines when the transparent call is made...

```
        import * as THREE from '../build/three.module.js';
        import { OrbitControls } from './jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';
        import { FBXLoader } from './jsm/loaders/FBXLoader.js';

        var container, controls;
        var camera, scene, renderer, light;

        var clock = new THREE.Clock();

        var mixer;

        init();
        animate();

        function init() {

            container = document.createElement( 'div' );
            document.body.appendChild( container );

            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
            camera.position.set( 500, 10, 500 );

            scene = new THREE.Scene();
            scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0x000000,0 );
            scene.background = null;
```

Comment: If there are any dom elements above the canvas in the dom hierarchy, that have a .background propery set, that can break the transparency. I've wasted hours on this :(
Let me know if that's it.. if not, I might have some other ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved, don't try and look first at the potentially complicated fix and instead look to the simple (DUH! while slapping own head). I had set the background css on the iframe as:

```
background:#;
```

but needed to be

```
background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
```

I had changed it earlier but the css was cached so no change.

Thanks manthrax for your help, it was your example that helped and sorry to waster your time. I will now sheepishly disappear for a while.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe don't set the background color at all?

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
#c {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  pointer-events: none;
}
#content {
  font-size: 7vw;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div>
    <h1>Cubes-R-Us!</h1>
    <p>We make the best cubes!</p>
  </div>
</div>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
  
<script type="module">
// Three.js - Transparent Canvas
// from https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/threejs-tips-transparent-canvas.html

import * as THREE from 'https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r115/build/three.module.js';

function main() {
  const canvas = document.querySelector('#c');
  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    canvas,
    alpha: true,
    premultipliedAlpha: false,
  });

  const fov = 75;
  const aspect = 2;  // the canvas default
  const near = 0.1;
  const far = 5;
  const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);
  camera.position.z = 2;

  const scene = new THREE.Scene();

  {
    const color = 0xFFFFFF;
    const intensity = 1;
    const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(color, intensity);
    light.position.set(-1, 2, 4);
    scene.add(light);
  }

  const boxWidth = 1;
  const boxHeight = 1;
  const boxDepth = 1;
  const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(boxWidth, boxHeight, boxDepth);

  function makeInstance(geometry, color, x) {
    const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
      color,
    });

    const cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    scene.add(cube);

    cube.position.x = x;

    return cube;
  }

  const cubes = [
    makeInstance(geometry, 0x44aa88,  0),
    makeInstance(geometry, 0x8844aa, -2),
    makeInstance(geometry, 0xaa8844,  2),
  ];

  function resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer) {
    const canvas = renderer.domElement;
    const width = canvas.clientWidth;
    const height = canvas.clientHeight;
    const needResize = canvas.width !== width || canvas.height !== height;
    if (needResize) {
      renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
    }
    return needResize;
  }

  function render(time) {
    time *= 0.001;

    if (resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer)) {
      const canvas = renderer.domElement;
      camera.aspect = canvas.clientWidth / canvas.clientHeight;
      camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    }

    cubes.forEach((cube, ndx) => {
      const speed = 1 + ndx * .1;
      const rot = time * speed;
      cube.rotation.x = rot;
      cube.rotation.y = rot;
    });

    renderer.render(scene, camera);

    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

main();
</script>
```